# How to query APIGEE for missing attribute

Tags: apigee

I need to find all entities in a collection that don't have a location associated with them. How does one do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the collection?  Is it something someone is posting to your API or a response payload? Or is this Apigee BaaS? Do you need to check an array or just a flat JSON payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a property that may or may not be there, the best way to approach this is to always add a default value for the property.  For example

POST /cats {"property_that_may_or_may_not_exist":"default"}

Then update the property when it needs to exist. If it doesn't exist yet, you can query with a positive match:

GET /cats?ql=select * where property_that_may_or_may_not_exist=default

In other words, the property is always there, it simply has a "false" value.